# How to change table of contents state with different screen widths

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using a javascript code to generate the table of contents automatically from H2 tags. It works very well.

But I want the status of table of contents to be "Hide" (Need to click on "Show" to show the table of contents) for screen widths less than 980px and "Show" for screens above 980px. Is there a way to do this?

This is jS code:

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
var postBody=document.querySelector('.post-body')
var titleChapter=postBody.querySelectorAll('h2')
if(1<=titleChapter.length){var i,leChapteraptor=[]
for(i=0;i<titleChapter.length;i++){anchorChapter='chapter-'+(i+1)
titleChapter[i].setAttribute('id',anchorChapter)
titleChapter[i].setAttribute('title','back to top')
leChapteraptor[i]='<li data-target='+"#"+anchorChapter+'>'+titleChapter[i].innerHTML+'</li>'}
$('.box_category').html('<p>Table of content <label></label></p><ul class="chapter">'+leChapteraptor.join('')+'</ul>')}else{$('.box_category').remove()}
$('.box_category p>label').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('show')
$(this).parent().parent().find('ul').slideToggle('slow')})
$('.box_category li').bind('click',function(){var target=$(this).attr('data-target')
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:($(target).offset().top)-70},'slow')})
for(k=0;k<titleChapter.length;k++){titleChapter[k].addEventListener('click',function(){$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:($('.box_category').position().top)},'slow')})}
//]]>
</script>
```

Css:

```
.box_category {background-color: #f0f1f5;margin-top: 22px;padding: 15px;border-left: 4px solid;border-color: #4285f4;}
.box_category p {font-size: 1.3em;text-align: center;}
.box_category p>label:after {content: '[Hide]';cursor: pointer;}
.box_category p>label.show:after {content: '[Show]';cursor: pointer;}
.box_category ul {margin: 10px 0 0;padding: 0;}
.box_category li {list-style-type: none;line-height: 1.8rem;cursor: pointer;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='box_category'/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by (t the status of table of contents to be "Hide")? do you want it to have a display: none;

Comment: u can achieve your goal by using [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) , or using [Javascript window match media](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp) , hope it helps u

Comment: yes, add style=display:none for screen < 980p and style=display:block for > 980px. How to??

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the `$(function() {...})` add the following:

```
windowWidth = $(this).width();
if (windowWidth < 980) {
     $(".box-category").addClass("hide");
     //Your code of adding an open button in the DOM
}
//...
$(".open-btn").click(function() {...}) //Handler for an open button
```

This code above will check whether size of the sreen when page loads is less than 980px, and if it's so, it'll hide table of contents

And then write a window resize handler:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = $(this).width();
        if (windowWidth < 980) {
            $(".box-category").hide();
        }
        else {
            if ($(".box-category").hasClass("hide")) {
                $(".box-category").show();
                $(".open-btn").remove();
            }
        }
 });
```

CSS for .hide class:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```